# Function declaration inside function which is inside object

Tags: javascript, function, methods, javascript-objects

It is interesting, just theoretically, not in real world.

1 - How can I call `inside()` function from outside?

2 - Is it common practice to create such a structure?

3 - What will be the value of `this` in `inside()` function (if it is possible to call from outside)?

```
 var obj = {
        method: function(){
            console.log('method function called!');
            function inside(){
                console.log('inside function called!')
                }
           }  
    }
```

Comment: 1) No 2) Yes 3) [As always](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this), depends on how it is called

Comment: Could you please explain in more details, if it is impossible to call inside() function (1), why it is common practice(2)? and it depends on what?

Comment: If it's impossible to call it from outside, that doesn't make it impossible to be called from inside `method` - and that's quite often pretty useful. Regarding `this`, please see the linked docs

Comment: I have already looked documentation you mentioned before writing this question, it was not clear for me. but last answer you wrote and Rayons answer really helped me to understand it. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. How can I call inside() function from outside? -> No, JavaScript has
   block level scope, hence anything defined inside function will not
   be accessible outside function. It could be called a private
   function.
2. Is it common practice to create such a structure? -> It is. If you
   want your function to be hidden from other part of your execution
   cycle.
3. What will be the the value of this in inside() function (if it is
   possible to call from outside)? -> Value of `this` depends on how
   the function is invoked. In your case, this will be `window` if
   `function` is called without any context hence `global(window)
   context`

```js
var obj = {
  method: function() {
    console.log('method function called!');

    function inside() {
      console.log(this);
      console.log('inside function called!');
    }
    inside();
  }
}

obj.method();
```